# Decrease the vertical height between text and horizontal rule

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I need to show a text with horizontal rule almost touching the text. that is the vertical height between the text and hr should be very less. This should be displayable in mobile safari browser.

http://pastie.org/1206301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the padding/margin to 0 of your hr: (note i put the HR inside the  because you don't want all HR's assuming that style. You could also give the < hr/> it's own CSS class too.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {color:red;}
h1 {color:#00ff00;}
p.ex {color:rgb(0,0,255);}
.new{vertical-align:text-bottom;}
.new hr{padding:0;margin:0;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="new">
    test text
    <hr/>
    <div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the margin and padding of the HR element to zero.

```
hr {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```